# Passing input to Iterator in Step Function along to its output while keeping iterator output

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function state machine that goes starts into parallel lambdas, and once all the parallel lambdas are done there is a final lambda that gets executed

Example definition

```
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using a map state to process elements of an array with a max concurrency of 2.",
  "StartAt": "Map",
  "States": {
    "Map": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.my_list",
      "Parameters": {
        "list_item.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
        "input_1.$": "$.input_1",
        "input_2.$": "$.input_2"
      },
      "MaxConcurrency": 2,
      "Next": "Final",
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Parallel Step",
        "States": {
          "Parallel Step": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<>:function:parallel-lambda:$LATEST",
              "Payload": {
                "Input.$": "$"
              }
            },
            "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
            "End": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Final": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<>:function:final-lambda:$LATEST",
        "Payload": {
          "Input.$": "$"
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the parallel lambdas is something like

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'n-successes': n_successes}
```

Right now the input to my `Final` lambda is getting a list of those outputs.  Which I do want.  But is there a way to pass on some of the input that went to the parallel lambdas onto the final lambda.

Ideally my final lambda's input would be something like

```
{'input_1': input_1_val,
 'input_2': input_2_val,
 'parallel_outputs': [{'statusCode': 200, 'n-successes': 5}, ...]
```

I know I could pass it in my parallel lambdas output but that seems inefficient to have the same input values repeated so many times in the output list

Comment: i have also same problem how to pass input to the map function how can i write code for ma function in .cs file .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use $.ResultPath instead of $.OutputPath

see [AWS Docs: Use ResultPath to Include the Result with the Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html#input-output-resultpath-append)